# Exclude specific sub-modules from product build

Tags: android, android-productflavors

Okay, so I have different product flavors and I have different submodules. Right to implement submodule, I do this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(path: ':A-Android')
    implementation project(path: ':B-Android')
    implementation project(path: ':C-Android')
}
```

Is it possible to implement, for instance, submodule `:A-Android` only for specific product flavor? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, can configure dependencies only for specific flavor. Here an excerpt from [Declare dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants#dependencies) documentation :

> Declare dependencies
>
> You can configure a dependency for a specific build variant or
>   [testing source set](https://developer.android.com/studio/test/index.html#sourcesets) by prefixing the name of the build variant or
>   testing source set before the Implementation keyword, as shown in the
>   following example.
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     // Adds the local "mylibrary" module as a dependency to the "free" flavor.
>     freeImplementation project(":mylibrary")
>
>     // Adds a remote binary dependency only for local tests.
>     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
>
>     // Adds a remote binary dependency only for the instrumented test APK.
>     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
> }
> ```
>
> For more information, see [Add build dependencies](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html).

So, if you have two flavors something like `production` and `development` flavor, then you can add the dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {
    productionImplementation project(path: ':A-Android')
    DevelopmentImplementation project(path: ':B-Android')

    ..
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks!
And is there a way to write productionImplementation project(path: ':A-Android') and pass multiple "path: ':X-Android'" paths for more than one submodule?